# import in NASM doesn't work?

Tags: windows, import, nasm

i'm trying to compile the following code on windows 7 (with NASM):

```
[BITS 32]

extern ExitProcess
import ExitProcess kernel32.dll
extern MessageBoxA
import MessageBoxA user32.dll

segment .data use32
Caption db 'Caption Text',0
Text db "My MessageBox Text.",0

segment .code use32
..start:
push dword 0
push dword Caption
push dword Text
push dword 0
call [MessageBoxA]

push dword 0
call [ExitProcess]
```

To compile this, I tried `nasm -o test.o test.asm`, but then it says:

```
test.asm:4: error: parser: instruction expected
test.asm:6: error: symbol `import' redefined
test.asm:6: error: parser: instruction expected
```

Why doesn't it work?

EDIT: ok. simple mistake... `nasm -o test.o -f obj test.asm` works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a known problem. Resolution suggested in http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/114989-nasm-import-directive-failing-expected-instruction-error.html

Comment: I used 'obj' as format and ALINK to link it. worked fine. thx

Answer (score -2):

You should not have to use Obj. That is meant for DOS not Windows. Yes, you can use a ton of compiler directives in your ASM code to make it work in Windows, but if you compile with type Win32, you will end up with code specifically that works in Windows. Unfortunately whoever wrote NASM worte it in such a way that import doesn't work in Win32 mode (even though it should, as import is a very standard, and required operation for working in Windows). And even MORE unfortunately is that the person who wrote NASM seems to have stopped adding/improving/upgrading the program and has basically abandoned the project. And with no way for the community to fix this bug our selves (the source code for NASM isn't publicly available), that leaves us with a HUGELY DEFECTIVE PRODUCT!

Comment: The source code for NASM isn't publicly available? [Then what's this?](https://github.com/letolabs/nasm)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm) is the source code for NASM.